# yield object inside asyncio function

Tags: python, async-await, python-asyncio

I'm trying to work with asyncio I tried this code where I process a list of elements ad I print the state of It (element) (working)
problem: how can I yield the element(object) when I do this I have this error **object async_generator can't be used in 'await' expression**

```py
import asyncio, random

async def process_element(element):
    print('starting', element)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())  # simulate IO-bound processing
    print('done', element)

async def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = await q.get()
        await process_element(element=value)
        q.task_done()

async def main():
    jobs = asyncio.Queue()

    for i in range(20):
        await jobs.put(i)

    for i in range(5):
        asyncio.create_task(do_stuff(jobs))

    await jobs.join()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: I could not reproduce this. Please run your code in freshly started interpreter. If you see this issue again, add full stacktrace fro investigation

Comment: what I wanna do is change the print with yield but when I do I have the error

Comment: Yield produces a generator which is meant to be exhausted with a `for` loop (or `async for` if the yield is from an async function). I'm not sure whether a `yield` in `process_elements` makes sense, but you _can_ have it if you want to. To yield objects from `process_element`, replace `await process_element(value)` with `async for obj in process_element(value): <...some processing...>`. Does that resolve your issue?

Comment: the yield is used to return the processing state

Comment: I'm afraid you will need to provide more information than that for us to be able to help you. What is "processing state", and why would you use `yield` to "return" it? Also, where would you return it to, who needs to observe that processing state? Please elaborate.

Comment: every thread will process an element and return the stat of that element (pending, processing, done, or error) and I should get the return to show the progress

Answer (score 0):

It is just a matter of receiving whatever you want to yield using an `async for` instead of a plain `await`:

```py
import asyncio, random

async def process_element(element):
    print('starting', element)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.random())  # simulate IO-bound processing
    yield element
    print('done', element)

async def do_stuff(q):
    while not q.empty():
        value = await q.get()
        async for response in process_element(value):
            print(f"process yield element: {response}")
        q.task_done()

async def main():
    jobs = asyncio.Queue()

    for i in range(20):
        await jobs.put(i)

    for i in range(5):
        asyncio.create_task(do_stuff(jobs))

    await jobs.join()

asyncio.run(main())
```

If for some reason you don't want to use "async for", you can call
the methods `__anext__` and `asend` on the async generator object
(which  is what is  returned by calling `process_element` after it contains an `yield` keyword).

Both `.__anext__` and `.asend` have to be awaited, and will throw `StopAsyncIteration` when the generator is exhausted (in contrast with `StopIteration` for non-async generators).

Comment: yes I did that, I can't et you when you talk about calling the methods can you please explain more